# Acces to array object via property like via index

Tags: javascript

I have a question.
 i have an array of objectc class product.
Is it possible to acces to specyfic object in array via his property. Like accesing with [index] in array ? Something like this:

```
PRODUCTS[PRODUCTS.product_name=uniquename].data.detail[detail.id = id].ov = parseInt(changeSignal.value);
```

Here is the PRODUCTS. it is and array of Product objects:

```
PRODUCTS: Product[] =[];
```

Here is the class Product

```
class Product {
  id:number;
  block: string;
  czas: string;
  data: ProductData
  product_name:string;
}
```

Comment: `PRODUCTS.product_name=uniquename` ???/

Comment: @up I edit question

Comment: What is PRODUCTS? How is it defined? Maybe you should be using an object instead of an array?

Comment: Change your data structure from an array to an object where keys will be unique product ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have and array of objects like this:

```
var products = [{
    id: 1, block: "b1", product_name: "p1"
}, {
    id: 2, block: "b2", product_name: "p2"
}, {
    id: 3, block: "b3", product_name: "p3"
}];
```

and you want to get the object which `product_name` is `p3` you need to loop through the array. For that you can use the array function `filter` like this:

```js
// List of products
var products = [{
 id: 1, block: "b1", product_name: "p1"
}, {
 id: 2, block: "b2", product_name: "p2"
}, {
 id: 3, block: "b3", product_name: "p3"
}];

// Find product by it's product_name
var prod = products.filter(function(p) {
  return p.product_name === "p3";
});

console.info(prod);
```

You can not use the notation like you have described. Many libraries like jQuery, or underscore have helper functions which can help you with finding the right object in the array.

The same done with underscore:

```js
// List of products
var products = [{
 id: 1, block: "b1", product_name: "p1"
}, {
 id: 2, block: "b2", product_name: "p2"
}, {
 id: 3, block: "b3", product_name: "p3"
}];

// Find product by it's product_name
var prod = _.findWhere(products, {product_name: "p3"});

console.info(prod);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is not like you are attempting. JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes (associative arrays).  In JavaScript, arrays always use numbered indexes, so whatever expression you have inside the square brackets must resolve to an integer.  xxxmatco's answer gives a good example of how to access properties via an array index and then subsequent dot notation.

Comment: 'In JavaScript, arrays always use numbered indexes'...  Not entirely true - you can use array['index'], array['tag'] etc in JS but you need to define the named parameters yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with your syntax, but Underscore can do this for you. For example:

```
   var list = [
        {name: "darin", age: 10},
        {name: "cody", age: 30},
        {name: "dave", age: 40},        
    ]

    var result = _.findWhere(list, {"name": "cody"}) ;
```

http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js